# Gridview loses ItemTemplate after columns are removed

Tags: asp.net, gridview, state, templatefield

I'm trying to bind a datatable to a gridview where I've removed some of the autogenerated columns in the code behind.

I've got two template columns and it seems that when I alter the gridview in code behind and remove the non-templated columns that the templates loose the controls that are in them.

Using the following as a sample, "Header A" will continue to be visible but "Header B" will dissapear after removing any columsn that are located at index 2 and above.  I'm creating columns in my codebehind for the grid as a part of a reporting tool.  If I don't remove the columns then there doesn't seem to be an issue.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header A"  >
            <ItemTemplate >
                  Text A
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                      Header B
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                      Text B
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

For i = 2 To DataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1
      DataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(2)
Next
```

**EDIT**

So from what I've read this seems to be a problem that occurs when the grid is altered.  Does anyone know of a good workaround to re-initialize the template columns or set them up again so that when the non-template columns are removed that hte templates don't get removed as well?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but... why are there any autogenerated columns when you've set "AutoGenerateColumns" to false?

Comment: I add them in the code behind myself.  For various resons I can't just databind my data to the control and have it create the columsn like you might typically expect..  There is a fair bit of messaging that has to happen first so I basically create he columsn and the parameters for them in my codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the GridView to have ViewState?  Try turning off ViewState.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" GridLines="Horizontal" EnableViewState="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

hi solved with `visibile=false`.
on databind .net will not associate values and don t create them on html page